# Model binding not same in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, angularjs-ng-model

I have strange situation the same code is not working as expected in chrome and firefox.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="modal" id="FeeModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Fee Paid<label>
        <input id="FeePaid" ng-model="feeModel.FeePaid" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button ng-click="feeModelUpdate()">Apply</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this is the code in contoroller:

```
//this is the method I call to open modal
$scope.addFee = function(section, index, isRecordingFee) {
    var data = { 
        section = section,
        index = index,
        isRecordingFee = isRecordingFee
    }

    $scope.feeModel = data;

    $(".popover").hide();
    $("#FeeModal").modal("show");
}

$scope.feeModelUpdate = function() {

    // in this method I have problem
    $scope.feeModel.FeePaid

}
```

In my method feeModelUpdate I want to access value from FeePaid but I have problems on diferent browsers.

On chrome this code is working and I have value in my FeePaid, but this is not working on Firefox.

So I presume this is some kind of issue in scoping in different browsers?

If I change my html code to:

```
ng-model="$parent.feeModel.FeePaid"
```

Then all of a sudden this is working in Firefox, but it's not working in Chrome. So I need help to find solution to this issue. I'm not sure what is wrong but it's odd that this code is working in one browser and not working in other, and vice versa.

Comment: first of all the method you say contains the problem, actually is not a proper method. Change it from what you have in `$scope.feeModelUpdate = function() {

    $scope.feeModel.FeePaid //do here what you need

}`

Comment: Thanks for pinpointing me error in questions code. That is code from my controller, I didn't put it in question as I should.

Comment: One more thing, I had a situation when the code didn't work in Chrome and was going crazy googling, but nothing. I just disabled all my extentions in Chrome and the code worked fine. Check that with the code you have. Also do you see any console errors or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with change in my controller code. I've initialized `feeModel` on start of the controller:

```
$scope.feeModel = {};

...

$scope.addFee = function(section, index, isRecordingFee) {

...
```

It solved the problems but I'm not sure why did this fixed the issues. If someone has some explanations it would be great if he can post it.